# NetworkX - path around a node

Tags: python, networkx

I use [NetworkX](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create the following graph.

[image: Networkx graph]

The graph is created using:

```
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(4,3)
```

After that two nodes are modified with respect to their positions (just to explain the figure, not necessary for the answer).

Using the following code:

```
G.neighbors((1, 1))
```

outputs:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

What I need in addition are the points:

```
[(0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]
```

This would make up a "loop" around (1, 1) containing all nodes in that "loop". Since I dont't know the correct naming in terms of graphs I have a hard time searching after what I'm looking for.

**EDIT:**

After being inspired by @orestiss and fiddling around I came up with this.

```
l = list()
center = (1, 1)
for neighb in G.neighbors(center):
    others = [n for n in G.neighbors(center) if n != neighb]
    for other in others:
        l.append([n for n in nx.common_neighbors(G, neighb, other) if n != center])
    l.append([neighb])
lf = list(set([item for sublist in l for item in sublist]))
```

With that I get all nodes which are in the cycle around *center*, except *center* itself.
This works also for boundary nodes.

Comment: This concept makes sense in a square lattice, but perhaps not for other graphs.  Can you tell us a bit more about why you're looking for this so that we can give an appropriate answer?

Comment: I work with square lattices for mesh generation for CFD simulations (so called block structured meshes). For being able to implement some mesh smoothing algorithms (e.g. angle based smoothing), I need the reference to those nodes. I have my own data structure, but I would like to adopt graphs, because there are many other functions already available there, which I can apply for my projects. And I like to get more knowledge about graphs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in this specific case would suffice to find which neighbours your neighbours have in common.

the code would be :

```
in_loop = set()
root = (1,1)

for neighb in G.neighbors(root):
    others = [n for n in G.neighbors((1,1)) if n != neighb]
    for other in others:
         if neighb in [x for x in G.neighbors(other) if x != root]:
              in_loop.add(neighb)
              break

print in_loop
```

Comment: That solves my question. Thanks for providing the logics and the code. So it looks to me, there is no dedicated function in NetworkX that does that.

Comment: You are wellcome @Andy, I haven't run the code so it might need some changes to run properly

Comment: I had to modify it slightly. The line "if neighb in " needed something like: "if G.neighbors(neighb) in ".
Need to refactor my code before I share it ;)